# How can I clean the condenser coils on my Maytag freezer

Tags: cleaning

The freezer part of the refrigerator in my kitchen is warm and I've come to realize the coils are quite dusty. But Maytag (and, I guess, Whirlpool) freezers don't have flat coils that I can easily brush or vacuum off.  They are sort of W shaped with the trough going across the width of the fridge so I can only really see the leading edge of the first "fold."

I found one suggestion of using a compressor to blow off the coils then clean up the dust behind but that seems to have only really affected the first section.  Another suggestion was to empty the fridge and tip it or lay it back and clean from underneath. I hate to think about that but I'm out of ideas.  Anyone here smarter than me? :-)

Comment: IME, if the freezer is warm, your problem is not really the external coils. Having removed many dust bunnies of terrifying proportions form the coils of fridges that were running nice and cold (if, perhaps, wasting a bit more electricity to do so than they might otherwise) I suspect you have a more dire problem and require a refrigeration service technician. Or it may be failing to defrost. Tipping the fridge back is problematic in that you should then let it stand, not running, for 24 hours before turning it back on, creating a problem of where you store your cold food in the meantime.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  With the fridge on the highest setting, I can get it down to 40°F.  I guess I have to find a Maytag repairman.  They're all lonely, right? :-/

Comment: First repairman came today.  Nothing obvious or easy. By process of elimination, he says that it's a coolant system problem, perhaps a slow leak.  BTW, never buy Maytag appliances! Their quality is so low that they they can only afford a 1-year warranty on major appliances.

Comment: I cleaned the coils by replacing the refrigerator. :-/

Comment: @Ecnerwal I've encountered the same problem as the OP. Our fridge would no longer cool. Turns out the coils needed cleaning. Works fine now. So, it *may* be the coils.